# Flexbox equal heights inside iframe not working?

Tags: css, iframe, flexbox

I'm having a problem with a flexbox layout inside an iframe. The layout works fine in a normal view, but once placed inside an iframe (like here in this snippet or codepen etc.), the flex children of the second flex column doesn't have equal heights anymore.

I can't really show you the difference, because all snippets are automatically placed in iframes...

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b-block__wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.b-block__item,
.b-block__item--large {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .b-block__item,
  .b-block__item--large {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.b-article,
.b-article--large {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; /* works in a div but not in an iframe */
  /* flex: 0 1 auto; // works but without equal heights */
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #eee;
}

.b-article:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.b-article--large {
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="b-block">
  <div class="b-block__wrap">
    <div class="b-block__item--large">
      <article class="b-article--large">Vivamus erat sit habitasse nisi quam penatibus proin nascetur hac volutpat porttitor ad condimentum mauris aenean fames lectus tincidunt inceptos
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="b-block__item">
      <article class="b-article">Convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna.
      </article>
      <article class="b-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque. Sed pharetra nibh eget orci convallis at posuere leo convallis. Sed blandit augue vitae augue scelerisque bibendum. Vivamus sit amet libero turpis, non venenatis urna. In blandit, odio convallis suscipit venenatis, ante ipsum cursus augue.
      </article>
      <article class="b-article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis lectus metus, at posuere neque.
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is there any workaround for this?
I already tried:

• Wrapping the `b-article` in the second `b-block__item` in an extra div
• Setting the flex property of the `b-article` in the second `b-block__item` to `flex: 0 1 33%;`

but no luck yet.
Is this even possible in an iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you also load the CSS in the iframe. To be able to help we need the code as it look when runned in the iframe (both the part with the iframe and the part being loaded in the iframe). Also, as accepting answers is a part of SO, you might want to start do that. It will for sure attract more experienced users to your questions.